# How to use SSDT to unit test a function using different inputs

Tags: unit-testing, sql-server-data-tools

I'm going through the documentation for creating [SSDT Unit Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851212(v=vs.103).aspx). All of the examples show testing stored procedures.  But what if I want to test scalar  or table-valued functions, where I can verify expected output for a given input.

*I am aware of [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org/). Although it is very easy to create unit tests in that framework, it is also tightly bound to the development database. I prefer to have my tests in a separate project. The fact the tests are in a Unit Test Project are a huge draw to me, which is why I decided to spend my effort on getting the SSDT unit tests fo fit my needs.*

I figured out how to create one test condition. (See screenshot).

In the *test code* block, I defined the input value `@ofDate = '2/1/2018'` and defined the expected output in the property window.

```
DECLARE @RC AS DATE, @ofDate AS DATE;

SELECT @RC = NULL,
       @ofDate = '2/1/2018';

SELECT @RC = [dbo].[GetMostRecentThursday](@ofDate);

SELECT @RC AS RC;
```

[image]

I can click the green plus in the "Test Conditions" panel and add a new test condition for scalar value (such as "if date is '2/2/2018' then return '2/1/2018'"), but I don't see a way to set a unique input for the new test condition.

In other words, how can I define a unique input parameter for a specific test condition?  Do I need to create another unit test file to test a new condition?

Comment: You should probably have 2 distinct tests (or 3 depending on your expected outcomes).  The first for Valid inputs.  The second for an InValid input, and test that you get your desired response when an invalid input is used.  The third would be if you have 2 different invalid responses, ie you could have value below minimum and above maximum Valid range that return 2 different outputs.

Comment: You should be able to determine the expected output of a Valid input without having to hard code it.

Comment: I am not sure how far did you go with your SSDT unit testing, but just a suggestion - take a look to tsqlt.org. It is far away better choice than the native SSDT/VS unit testing.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev, I looked at tsqlt. It's far easier to design tests. The problem is that it's tightly bound with the database. I'd like something that I can easily keep in a separate project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user7396598 gave me the hint I needed to figure it out. The key *is* creating a new unit test, but *not* a new unit test class.

Although there is a "shorter" method to do the following, I prefer the one I'm presenting because there is less chance of coder error. Your boilerplate is correctly set up, so you can focus the specific items you need to set up for the test.

1. Right-click the function you are testing and create unit test.

[image]

2. This is they key: *insert a unit test into the pre-existing test class*.

[image]

3. It looks familiar, but that's the point. All you need to do is set your input values and your test conditions.

And that is how you add a new test.